# Create new EF object with foreign key reference without loading whole rereference object

Tags: entity-framework-4

I want to create a new EF object which references another object (the aspnet userId in my example) without loading the foreign (key) object.

So essentially I want to do the following:

```
buskerSet bs = new buskerSet();
bs.Title = title;
bs.Image = image;
bs.Created = DateTime.Now;
//The following will crash, because bs.aspnet_Users is null
bs.aspnet_Users.UserId = userId;

context.SaveChanges();
```

In the bs.aspnet_UsersReference I can't find anything that would help..

SOLUTION:

```
aspnet_Users user = new aspnet_Users { UserId = userId };
context.AttachTo("aspnet_Users", user);
set.aspnet_Users = user;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AyKarsi,

Have a look at Alex James EF blog post about using stub objects, it explains how to do what you want.

[TIP 26 - How to avoid database queries using Stub Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx)

Hope that helps,
Nick